# Recover values from a customer attribute

Tags: magento-1.9, php, attributes

hi I use **this code** to retrieve **data from a customer's attribute** called "pagamento"

```
if(Mage::getSingleton('customer/session')->isLoggedIn()) 
{
$customerId = Mage::getModel('customer/session')->getCustomer()->getId();
}
$customer = Mage::getModel('customer/customer')->load($customerId);
echo $customer->getpayment();
```

until now the attribute was a text box and returned the correct value to me.
now I have to change the attribute which will be multiple choice

if I leave the code so I get a number and not the text of the multiple choice
How can I get the text?
Furthermore, if multiple values are selected, how can I get all the results?
Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Three choices:

```
1. $attributeText = $customer->getAttributeText('pagamento');

2. $attributeText = $customer->getResource()->getAttribute('pagamento')->getFrontend()->getValue($customer);

3. $attributeText = $customer->getResource()->getAttribute('pagamento')->getFrontend()->getAttribute()->getFrontendLabel();
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply

the first solution gives no results
the second works with the first value of multiple choice
the third gives me the name of the attribute

I will use the second one. Is there any way to get all the results of multiple choice?

Comment: The second one should gives you all the attribute values, check your attribute config and the selected values of this customer

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I checked and only returns the first value of the multiple selection.
For example, if I select them all the first one appears, if I remove the first one the second one appears